# TI SmartConfig Framework not working in iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, i386

I used TI smartConfig Framework in my APP to Configure CC3000 Modules.The Code downloaded from Texas Instruments Site was not working in Simulator and Showing the following error, but it's working when Device connected.

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Naresh/CC3000_Smartconfig_iOS_Source-1.1/src/CC3x/libFTC_DEBUG_ARM_64.a, missing required architecture i386 in file /Naresh/CC3000_Smartconfig_iOS_Source-1.1/src/CC3x/libFTC_DEBUG_ARM_64.a (2 slices)
ld: warning: ignoring file/Naresh/CC3000_Smartconfig_iOS_Source-1.1/src/CC3x/libFTC_RELEASE_ARM_64.a, missing required architecture i386 in file /Naresh/CC3000_Smartconfig_iOS_Source-1.1/src/CC3x/libFTC_RELEASE_ARM_64.a (2 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_FirstTimeConfig", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in CC3xUtility.o
objc-class-ref in CC3xMainViewController.o
objc-class-ref in CC3xMainViewController_iPad.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this post](https://e2e.ti.com/support/wireless_connectivity/f/851/t/298073), it does not work on Simulator because you need real hardware to test its functionality. However, apparently they think that apps using this library don't have any other function/UI to test in simulator. That's why they don't provide universal library.